# Python3 is suddenly gone (on macOS) - used it for at least a year

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pip, homebrew

I had **python2** installed on my macOS and I **parallel installed python3** (*without homebrew*). It worked perfect and I could use `python3` and `pip3` from every directory without problems parallel to `python` and `pip` for version 2.

Some days ago I did not find `pip3` and I had to set an alias to `python3 -m ...` (*I thought I didn't use it before but I had!*). Today in the morning I worked with python3 without problems and now `python3` got a `command not found` but I cannot find it on my directories, too.

**Where is my python3? And why it is gone?**

The only reason I see is that I installed `homebrew` about a week ago for installing mutt. Is it possible that the `brew upgrade` function has destroyed paths or even installations?

Would be great to get help from you!
Thanks a lot.

Comment: its hard to say without knowing how you installed python3

Comment: @avigil I searched in my todo-files but I did not find it. I keep searching ...

Comment: the homebrew changelog mentions some changes to the `python` formula released on March 1 that may have caused your issue: https://brew.sh/2018/01/19/homebrew-1.5.0/

Comment: I found that python was in /usr/bin/python and python3 was located in /usr/local/bin/python3. But now both places I can only find python3. Very mysterious ...
Is there a possibility to update only /usr/local/bin/python2 again to 3 without losing all libraries I installed before?
But do this change at homebrew can downgrade my python?

Comment: I tried `brew upgrade python3` and now there is with only half of a second of installing a python3 at /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.4_3. And `python3` works in every directory??? I don't understand. Does `brew` changed my directories? What's that `Cellar`? And do you think my old libraries are moved with?

Comment: `homebrew` installs everything to `/usr/local/Cellar` and then symlinks to `/usr/local/bin`. It does not make changes outside `/usr/local`

Comment: Here is the link of python in `/usr/bin`: `python2.7 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7`

Is it right that when I installed python3 before in /usr/local/bin/python3 that brew moves the installation to its own directory? Why? Is it better not to work with brew?

And I can not start python2 (only with an alias to `/usr/bin/python2.7`)! How can I "re-animate" my old configurations?

Comment: If a command is not available, it means you have modified your `PATH` variable. In your `.bash_profile` file, modify `PATH` so that it includes `/usr/local/bin` directory: `PATH="${PATH}":/usr/local/bin`. At the end of the file, add line `export PATH`, restart the terminal.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the `PATH` variable was modified but not from me - I think `homebrew` has done that. I realized it when `vim` has other configurations for filetypes, too.
But I do not know why `brew` downgraded one of the pythons ... seems not to be the best package manager for mac ... :(

Comment: it works fine in the majority of cases but as I said, its really hard to know whats going on if you can't describe  how you configured your previous installation. `brew upgrade` will not do anything for not installed packages, so that suggests you installed `python3` with homebrew before

Comment: maybe going forward follow suggestions from https://stackoverflow.com/q/47082736/7088038

Comment: Thanks for your help. Every problem leads to new learning lessons: Now I know much more about the directory-structures, different versions on the same os and about the $PATH-variable. Thanks for your impulses!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe someone else has the same problem. Therefore the **steps for my solution**:

- the `which` command shows me the directories of the versions linked everywhere in the system
- the argument `--version` gave me an overview of where I found the different versions of `python` and `vim` (*for more informations about the directory-changes I checked vim, too*)
- looking at `echo $PATH` and `ls -lha /etc/paths*` I knew more about the current sequence of possible directories of installations and about changes (`brew` saved the original file as `/etc/paths~orig`)
- with these informations I first upgraded with `brew upgrade python3` (*it seems that my installed libraries stayed like in the days before the mysterious loss of python3*), then I could change the paths and add some alias to get the environment I want to work with

Now everything seems to be like before the problems. If I will notice any further changes I now have the knowledge to solve them within some minutes. *Good feeling!*

It's not solved why `brew` downgraded the python3-installation because I'm sure not having installed it in the days of adding python3 to python2. But that isn't very important.

*Thanks to the helpers - especially @avigil.*

Comment: Great. Then it was a good decision to explain my workflow to the solution.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same strange behavior after a `brew upgrade`: `python 3` suddenly disappeared.

`brew install python3`

told me that

```
python 2.7.14 is already installed
To upgrade to 3.6.5, run `brew upgrade python`
```

So that is what I did. The homebrew install of `python 2` is gone now, but can be installed again using `brew install python@2` .

Answer (score 1):

In case this helps, I had a similar problem where a homebrew upgrade made python3 seem to disappear.

`brew install python3`

...told me python3 was already installed and just needed to be linked with

`brew link python`

Ran it, and the symlinks it created seem to have resolved the issue.